# App working in dev mode however after packaged the JavaScript wont work

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm new to Electron and working on creating a basic app, the app itself works great while in dev mode, however once I package the app for windows none of the buttons work correctly. I have tried using the browserify but with no luck. I have also messed around with the nodeIntergration set to true and false but that didn't seem to fix my issue either. I understand that require() module is node a server side thing and that the browser cannot natively support it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Also if you require any additional information or code please let me know.

The error I'm getting is: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at index.html:17"

**Main JS**

```
const electron = require('electron');
var app = require('electron').app;
var BrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

var mainWindow = null;

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  if (process.platform != 'darwin')
   app.quit();
});

app.on('ready', function() {    
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({webPrefrences: {nodeIntergration: true, enableRemoteModule: true}, 
width: 600, height: 410, frame: true, transparent: true, resizable: false, icon: 
'C:/Users/cody/Projects/QuickLaunch/app/assets/icons/win' + '/icon.ico'});  
mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');  
mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
mainWindow = null;

 });  
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css"/>
<title>Quick Launch</title>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">     

<body style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
  <div id="title-bar">
    <div id="title-bar-btns">
      <script>
      (function () {

        const remote = require('electron').remote;

        function init() {
          document.getElementById("min-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            const window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
            window.minimize();
      });

        document.getElementById("close-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
          const window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
          window.close();
        });
      };

      document.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (document.readyState == "complete") {
          init();
        }
      };

      })();
     </script>

       <button id="min-btn">-</button>
       <button id="close-btn">x</button>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: why don't you switch from absolute paths to relative? this path only exists in your machine: `C:/Users/cody/Projects/QuickLaunch/app/assets/icons/win`. And `document.getElementById("min-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {` ? why not just  `document.getElementById("min-btn").onclick = function(e) {....}`